# autoNumeric with browserify

Tags: jquery, browserify

I am trying to pull in the jquery autoNumeric library with browserify.  At runtime, my DOM elements do not have the .autoNumeric() function attached -- it's as though autonumeric is not intializing or something.

Has anyone been successful in getting this to work, and do you have any pointers?

Comment: For info, this question is linked to that [opened issue](https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric/issues/388). The upcoming v3 changes how we bundle the library a bit, so perhaps that would solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

As of yesterday, AutoNumeric in the `next` [branch](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/tree/next) does support Browserify!

Comment: That's great news!  As soon as this is a release version, we'll grab it and give feedback.